# localStorage - get Key container name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if it is possible to return localStorage items that all share part of a key name.

keys might be titled as:

```
task-0
task-1
task-2
fav-1
fav-4
```

but I want to just return the items with key's named 'task-'

I got this far but, the issue is... it just counts the length of all localstorage keys, not by the name.

```
var i = 0;

for( i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        $("#tasks").append("<li id='task-"+ i +"'>"+ '<span class="taskSpan">' + localStorage.getItem('task-' + i) +'</span>' + '<a href="#">x</a>' +  '<img    src="img/fav.png" class="addafav">' +  "</li>");

   }
```

Comment: Store an array called `task` instead.

Comment: good idea, will give it a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var key in localStorage){
    if(key.indexOf("task") === 0){
        //...
    }
}
```